# How can I put an array into data store using scutil on Mac?

Tags: macos, kerberos

Using scutil on a Mac, I know how to create a dict and put it inside the data store.

However, my system shows a key whose value is just an array:

```
$ scutil
> show Kerberos-Default-Realms
<array> {
  0 : ATHENA.MIT.EDU
}
```

How can I manually create an entry like that? I need to do this in my automatic test.

Comment: nice that you do a "`show`", but what I really want to see is how you create your dictionary.

Comment: That's what I'm asking for. That entry is created by the system. This is an OS X server.

Answer (score 2):

I may have found the answer (revised):

```
$ scutil
> help

Available commands:

help                          : list available commands
f.read file                   : process commands from file
quit                          : quit

d.init                        : initialize (empty) dictionary
d.show                        : show dictionary contents

d.add key [*#?] val [v2 ...]  : add information to dictionary
      (*=array, #=number, ?=boolean)
d.remove key                  : remove key from dictionary

list [pattern]                : list keys in data store
add key ["temporary"]         : add key in data store w/current dict
get key                       : get dict from data store w/key
set key                       : set key in data store w/current dict
show key ["pattern"]          : show values in data store w/key
remove key                    : remove key from data store
notify key                    : notify key in data store

n.list ["pattern"]            : list notification keys
n.add key ["pattern"]         : add notification key
n.remove key ["pattern"]      : remove notification key
n.changes                     : list changed keys
n.watch                       : watch for changes
n.cancel                      : cancel notification requests
```

To recreate the example in the question above:

```
> d.init
> d.add Kerberos-Default-Realms * ATHENA.MIT.EDU
> d.show
<dictionary> {
  Kerberos-Default-Realms : <array> {
    0 : ATHENA.MIT.EDU
  }
}
```

... and crap, that doesn't do exactly what you need, now does it? I mean, sure you have an array with the right values, but that array is in a dictionary.

You were looking for something more to the tune of:

```
> d.show
<array> {
    0 : ATHENA.MIT.EDU
}
```

So that means we need something more like:

```
> a.init
a.init: unknown, type "help" for command info
```

Figures... wait! What if I:

```
> get Kerberos-Default-Realms
> d.show
<array> {
  0 : ATHENA.MIT.EDU
}
```

Sweet, now my "current dictionary" IS an array, so I should be able to work something out from here:

```
> d.add Kerberos-Default-Realms ATHENA.MIT.EDU ZEUS.MIT.EDU
d.add: data (fetched from configuration server) is not a dictionary.
```

Nope... That was my last hope... I know an NSArray is a valid NSObject, I just don't think scutil was built to support adding or modifying an NSMutableArray.

Obviously there is some way to get it into the dynamic store (because Kerberos-Default-Realms IS an array), but scutil looks like a dead end to me... Only one thing left to do:

```
> quit
```